# Python: how to process list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.6

I am trying to store discount codes and amounts from this json. I am not going to know how many dicts will be in the list.

```
  "discount_codes":[
     {
        "code":"STUDENT",
        "amount":"10.00",
        "type":"percentage"
     },
     {
        "code":"TEACHER",
        "amount":"15.00",
        "type":"percentage"
     }
  ]
```

I am trying this, but it does not work:

```
for codes, x in enumerate(discount_codes):
    discount_code = codes['x']['code']
    discount_amount = codes['x']['amount']
    print (discount_code)
    print (discount_amount)
```

Comment: Should be ``codes[x]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate on list return the index and value and in your case value is a dictionary, get the value from dictionary as below code:

```
for index, value in enumerate(discount_codes):
print(index)
print(value)
discount_code = value['code']
discount_amount = value['amount']
print(discount_code)
print(discount_amount)
#print (discount_code)
#print (discount_amount)
```

Added the complete code and execution as an image: [image]